# Partition drives before RAID1 or after

Tags: partitioning, raid

I have a data server with an SSD for Ubuntu and 2 HDD (4TB) for my data.  Both to be put in RAID1 configuration.

The data will be divided for /home, /nextcloud, /gitlab (respectively 500 GB, 2TB, 1TB).

Do I have to partition the 2 drives first according to the description and then put those partitions in RAID, or can I put the drives in RAID and then partition the RAID drive afterward?

Comment: Just noted that the three partitions you propose do not add up to the full 4 TB of the drives.

Comment: Both are possible depending on how you set things up. What “infrastructure” so you plan to set up the RAID? A (real or “fake”) hardware RAID with a dedicated chipset or some software solution like dm-raid, mdadm or LVM?

Comment: I use mdadm and create partitions, set them as type raid, then create the filesystem on the md device.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
-Juan
I know that the disk is not fully used the last partiton will be set to 100%.
-David
For raid I use mdadm.
Is there a difference in possibilities to set up partitions between software RAID and hardware RAID??
-hatterman
Can you explain how you partition after you have set up RAID with mdadm.
If I use parted, I can not choose between primary or extended and I got the message 'to many primaries' and all partitons are lost (in parted)

appreciate any explanation on the matter.